# ISDN and DSL comparison

Tags: adsl

From Wikipedia: "Integrated Services Digital Network (ISDN) is a set of communication standards", and for DSL: "Digital subscriber line is a family of technologies". My question is:
Is DSL built on top of ISDN and what are the differences?
I am a bit confused, since both describe ways of transmitting data over telephone lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't really compare those two technologies.

ISDN is a network protocol encompassing practically the whole OSI model from physical to application layer.

xDSL is a family of physical-layer line protocols running between two interfaces (point-to-point). There are ADSL and VDSL variants that allow the co-existence with POT and ISDN on the same line using a frequency splitter. This is often called *DSL over ISDN*, but it's actually more *DSL besides ISDN* because the ISDN (or POTS) doesn't know a thing about DSL.

Comment: IDSL is ISDN with the signaling/channelizing removed. ("raw" ISDN, if you will)